# How can i convert a binary number into 2's complement without using "if" or any kinds of loops or mathematical operations (if possible)

Tags: c, binary, twos-complement

As the title says, i need to find a way to convert a binary number into 2's complement, sounds easy but i can't use loops such as while, for,... or "if-then" or math operations like +-*/%. I tried this code for 1's complement and it works:

```
int main(){


bool a,b,c,d;
  scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
  a = !a;
  b = !b;
  c = !c;
  d = !d;
  printf("%d%d%d%d",a,b,c,d);
}
```

But i'm having a problem converting it to 2's complement since it's forbidden to use +. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact problem statement? Do you really asked to read a 4 bits of a number from the input, or it is your understanding of a problem?

Comment: Anyway, as it stands the easiest way to do it for 4-bit number is a lookup table.

Comment: `bool a; ... scanf("%d", &a);` is UB as `bool` is not certainly the same as `int`.

Comment: `a`..`d` are supposed to be the digit of the number? Do you mean to negate it in 2's complement? You can use the property of the xor and the fact that -x is ~x+1 which is keeping all the lowers zero up to the first one (included) and then negating the rest of the bits.

Comment: To add to a previous comment - to avoid any arithmetic operations, it can be a 4-dimensional lookup table, indexed with `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your example, I assume you are given the digits of a binary number and you need to negate it, considering it in two's complement format.
Without control flow statement or arithmetic operations, but with logic operators allowed.

You can exploit the fact that `-x` is `~x + 1` in two's complement and that the latter is equivalent to keeping all the least significant bits up to the first one, included, and then negating the rest.

```
10010100 => 01101100
```

This is easy to accomplish with the use of a boolean flag to xor with each digit. The flag is initially false so that it won't change the value of the bits but as soon as a one is found, it is permanently switched to true.
To set the flag to one without the use of an `if`, we use the value of the current digit and or it with the flag (so that it stays permanently true).

Here's a proof of concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   //This represents 7, the MSb is on the far right
   int digits[] = {0, 1, 1, 1};
   int flag = 0;
   
   
   digits[3] ^= flag;
   flag |= digits[3];
   digits[2] ^= flag;
   flag |= digits[2];
   digits[1] ^= flag;
   flag |= digits[1];
   digits[0] ^= flag;
   flag |= digits[0];

   printf("%d%d%d%d\n", digits[0], digits[1], digits[2], digits[3]); 
   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the 2's complement by adding 1 to the 1's complement.

For your binary number in `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` (in order from most to least significant digit), first find the 1's complement by inverting:

```
a = !a;
b = !b;
c = !c;
d = !d;
```

Then use logical operations to increment the value one bit at a time:

```
// Truth table:
// +----------+----------++-----------+-----------+
// | carry_in | value_in || carry_out | value_out |
// +----------+----------++-----------+-----------+
// |     0    |     0    ||     0     |     0     |
// |     0    |     1    ||     0     |     1     |
// |     1    |     0    ||     0     |     1     |
// |     1    |     1    ||     1     |     0     |
// +----------+----------++-----------+-----------+

carry_in = 1;

carry_out = carry_in & d;
d ^= carry_in;

carry_in = carry_out;

carry_out = carry_in & c;
c ^= carry_in;

carry_in = carry_out;

carry_out = carry_in & b;
b ^= carry_in;

carry_in = carry_out;

carry_out = carry_in & a;
a ^= carry_in;

carry_in = carry_out;
```